# How can I run my e2e test scenario against a Django application with Angular.js frontend?

Tags: django, angularjs, jasmine

I want to do end to end test as described in the documentation Angular.js using a frontend based on angular-seed. The backend is written using django. When I try to use the jstestdriver  (and the proxy option) I receive messages from jetty saying that GET requests to this URLs are not allowed.

How can I fix this? Are there other ways to run my tests in such a setup?

Do I understand it correctly that it's just common Jasmine and the test driver is more or less just a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsTestDriver doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, you can also try to run the test with PhantomJS for example: https://github.com/jcarver989/phantom-jasmine

Comment: Does that allow me to access a backend server?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it's a good alternative to check :) I personally use https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine for driving PhantomJS and quite happy with it, but haven't done extensive testing with a live server yet

Answer (score 5):

[Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) is currently the supported test runner. Here's my `testacular-e2e.conf.js` file.

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];


autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

singleRun = true;

proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:3000/'
};

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

The important part is `proxies`. It configures testacular to use your server. If I'm not mistaken, Django runs on port 8000 in development. So `proxies` would look like this:

```
proxies = {
  '/': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
};
```

After installing testacular via npm and creating this config file, you can then start your back end server and run your e2e tests like so:

```
$ testacular start config/testacular-e2e.conf.js
```

Comment: You might want to clarify. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Miguel, user1680104 asked "Are there other ways to run my tests in such a setup?" This is the way to run AngularJS e2e tests against your own server. What isn't clear about the answer?

Comment: @ChristianSmith  WOOPS! I was reviewing this post, and I thought it was a question! Sorry. My bad. :P

Comment: @Miguel Edited for clarity. This is my first answer after finding what I need on SO for quite some time. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @ChristianSmith how do you setup your data for tests? It's cool, that you can run karma/testacular against real API instead mocks, but without real data it's not such useful.

Comment: @yanoo My backends tend to be written with Node/Express. I generally config a separate test environment in Express to hit an isolated test db and port, and point proxies at that port. For server-side integration tests I use a homemade "factory" to add test-specific data and then flush the db before every test or block of tests. For client e2e tests, I load all the data once before running the tests with a custom grunt task. Curating test data and is a little extra work, but definitely worth the trouble for production code.